# Xcode Server iOS Trigger issues error 35

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, xcode-bots, xcode-server

I'm using Xcode 9.0.1

we increased the maximum number of processes until the next restart

```
sudo launchctl limit maxproc 2000 2500
```

I am having this issue while running integrations in Xcode Server.

> Assertion: Exception trying to execute trigger:
>   NSInternalInconsistencyException: Couldn't posix_spawn: error 35

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For anyone coming to this issue via googling "Couldn't posix_spawn: error 35"

Check your activity monitor. There may be a bunch of idle processes. For me, I ran into this error message ala source tree when I have a ton of idle python processes. Killing them all seemed to resolve the issue. I've been having this issue more since upgrading to mojave but it seems to have existed in prior versions of osx as well.

Comment: For me I have a ton of `DTServiceHub` processes running. `pkill -9 DTServiceHub` helped.

Answer (score 0):

I can see we didn't introduce any code change before the issue happened. Just found that the server has 8 simulators opened. After closing all of the simulators the integrations are working correctly again.